# Find the total charge of the sphere when density is given

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge

You have a sphere with a charge density of $\rho=Ar^4$, where $A$ is some constant and the sphere has a radius $R$. What is the total charge of the sphere?

I know that:

$$Q=\int\int\int \rho \ \mathrm{d}V$$

I make a switch to spherical coordinates

$$Q=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{R} Ar^6sin(\theta) \ \mathrm{d}r \ \mathrm{d}\theta \ \mathrm{d}\phi$$

Now I evaluate it
$$Q=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{AR^7}{7}sin(\theta) \ \mathrm{d}\theta \ \mathrm{d}\phi$$
This is the part that confuses me. $AR^7/7$ is a constant so we can factor that out, but the issue is with the integral of $sin(\theta)$ is $0$, But if it is zero then the net charge is also zero.

Comment: This is a Mathematics question (about integration). The reference to "charge" doesn't justify it to be a Physics question (about electrostatics).

Comment: Note that MathJax (as LaTex) has its own terms for trigonometric functions `\sin,\cos etc` instead of plain text $\:sin,cos\:$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limits of integration in spherical coordinates are wrong.
The proper limits are:
$$Q=\int_\limits{0}^{2\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{R} Ar^6\sin(\theta) \ \mathrm{d}r \ \mathrm{d}\theta \ \mathrm{d}\phi$$
$$Q=\int_\limits{0}^{2\pi}\int_\limits{0}^{\pi}\frac{AR^7}{7}\sin(\theta) \ \mathrm{d}\theta \ \mathrm{d}\phi$$
$$Q=\int_\limits{0}^{2\pi}\frac{2AR^7}{7}d \phi=\frac47\pi AR^7$$

Comment: I downvoted your answer for two reasons : (1) This is a Mathematics question (about integration). The reference to "charge" doesn't justify it to be a Physics question (about electrostatics). (2) Due to SE policy we must not give complete or near complete answers to homework-and-exercises type questions.

Comment: Note that MathJax (as LaTex) has its own terms for trigonometric functions `\sin,\cos etc` instead of plain text $\:sin,cos\:$ etc.

Comment: Also we could have a more elegant and compact form of definite integral symbols with limits if we use the `\limits_{a}^{b}` option, for example here : `\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{R}` which yields $$\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{R}$$